# Separate lines with blank lines in Vim?

Tags: vim, newline, shortcut, multiline

I am dealing with a block of comments like:

```
//this is comment 1
//this is comment 2
//this is comment 3
//this is comment 4
```

I would like to make it look like:

```
//this is comment 1

//this is comment 2

//this is comment 3

//this is comment 4
```

Is there a Vim shortcut to make this transformation on selected lines while staying in command mode?

Comment: I check back in ten minutes and I've got 3+ great answers!  I'm now using: Select lines with <Shift> + V, type `:g//norm o`.  I don't know which is more amazing, vim or the StackOverflow community!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `:substitute` command. With the cursor anywhere on the
first of the lines:

```
:,+3s/$/\r
```

This inserts an additional newline at the end of each line.

You can also use the `:global` command. With the cursor anywhere on
the first of the lines, run:

```
:,+3g//norm o
```

For each of the next four lines, this executes the `o` Normal-mode
command, adding a new blank line.

In both of the commands, the `,+3` prefix is a *range* for the
command, see `:help range`. Briefly, the comma separates the addresses
of the starting and ending lines of the range, where the current line
is used if we omit the former of the two addresses. The `+3` address
refers to the line that is three lines below from the current line.

Rather than specifying a range, e.g., `,+3`, for either of these
commands, you can use the `V` Normal-mode command to make a Visual
block across all the lines that you want. Then typing `:` to begin the
command will auto-fill the range specifying the visual block, and you
can then enter either of the two commands starting with `s` or `g`:

```
:'<,'>s/$/\r
```

Comment: Can you explain what `,` means?

Comment: when using line numbers in ranges, they are in format n,m. There are some special cases like ,+3, which means three lines onwards from the current line

Answer (score 1):

You can use a macro:

```
qao<esc>jq
```

then use `3@a` to apply the macro 3 times over the last lines.

where:

```
qa    "Start recording a macro named a
o     "Insert new line under current line
<esc> "Exit insert mode
j     " Move down next line
q     " end macro
```

Answer (score 1):

Select your visual selection with <kbd>V</kbd>

Then run a regex replace to replace one line break with two

`:s/\n/\r\r/g`

Answer (score 1):

One can use the command

```
:g/^/pu_
```

on the whole buffer (by default) or on a selected range of lines.

Comment: Can you explain what this command is doing?  I haven't figured out a good way to systematically reference vim/regex commands.

Answer (score 0):

Select the lines you want with <kbd>V</kbd>

Then type <kbd>:</kbd> and `s/\ze/\r`

Comment: the %V is redundant and it doesn't add a line break after the last line of the selection

Comment: The question does not mention a line break after the last line and indeed \%V is redundant while in visual mode linewise